# Full-screen background image blurred on iphone

Tags: html, css, iphone, responsive-design

I try to make main section with full-screen background image. It works at Android devices, but don't work at iPhone. Instead full-screen background image I get a small part of image.

[image]

I have next main section html code:

```
<div id="main" class="parallax-100-percents full-page-img h-100"
     style="background-image: url(resources/img/main/desc-with-flowers-100-m.jpg)">
    <div class="container h-100">
       ...
    </div>
</div>
```

And folloving style classes:

```
.parallax-100-percents {
  /* Set a specific height */
  height: 100%;
  /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
  background: no-repeat fixed center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.full-page-img {
  /* Full height */
  height: 100%;
  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background: no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

You can try it http://your-event.store

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `height: 100%`, try the `vh` unit, which takes in consideration the size of the screen. `height: 100vh` for example.

```
.parallax-100-percents {
  /* Set a specific height */
  height: 100vh;
  /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
  background-image: url(resources/img/main/desc-with-flowers-100-m.jpg);
  background: no-repeat fixed center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.full-page-img {
  /* Full height */
  height: 100vh;
  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background: no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

I removed the style tag from your HTML file. It's a good practice to keep all styling in the css file.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `h-100` class from the `#main` element and try.